# Number ranges intersection search in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have records with 2 columns **from** and **to**
Users can filter results by selecting or entering **from** ant **to** values
How to properly implement this thing with Laravel.
What I have now is simple

```
$query->where("field_to", '<=', $field_to);
$query->where("field_from", '>=', $field_from);
```

But this will not work for example if in database values are 10 and 100 but user inputs 50 and 200. I need some kind of intersection check. Or I overengineering something?

Comment: What are `field_from` and `field_to` used for?

Comment: It's define company profit range this could be 1000 - 3000 for example.

Comment: So if values in the database are 10 and 100 and user enters 50 and 200 the result should be empty but if they enter 15 and 25 it should show one result correct?

Comment: That would be easy, but what I think that it should not be empty in first case, because 50 - 200 have 50,51,52,53... which is in range of 10 - 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like this:

```php
$field_to = 50;
$field_from = 200;

$query->where(function ($query) use ($field_from) {
    $query->where('field_from', '<=', $field_from)
        ->where('field_to', '>=', $field_from);
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($field_to) {
    $query->where('field_from', '<=', $field_to)
        ->where('field_to', '>=', $field_to);
});
```

This will catch your scenario. For example if record in the database is 50 and 100 and the user enters these values:

- 55 and 70: **Catch**
- 70 and 150: **Catch**
- 150 and 200: **Not Catch**
- 20 and 30: **Not Catch**
- 20 and 75: **Catch**

Comment: Hm, don't know why but still getting strange results in database there is 0 and 10, this query counting 0: select count(*) as aggregate from `ads` where ((`employees_count_from` <= '50' and `employees_count_to` >= '50')) and `status` in ('publish')

Comment: The range you provided in the query is 50 and 50. `employees_count_from` less than 50 and `employees_count_to` greater than 50 with `publish` status. And by the way, the query is not the query I provided in answer, you have to use `or` too. Abnother thing that you used string. You should use numbers like `50` not `'50'`

Comment: @RomkaLTU So you query would be something like this: `select count(*) as aggregate from ads where ((employees_count_from <= 50 and employees_count_to >= 50) or (employees_count_from <= 100 and employees_count_to >= 100)) and status in ('publish') `

Comment: It's same just different field name. And in case when 50 is provided by the user it will not find anything. In data base there is 0 and 10.

Comment: Nevermind added condition to omit additional where.